# Grab from a webcam

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, streaming

> On Linux it is easy to use an audio or video grabbing device as input to FFmpeg:
>
> ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/dsp -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 out.flv

Today someone in kirupa forums said they used to create flash webcam netstream but now just use linux. That would be great but how do you do it!? I mean how would you do it in Linux to simultaneously grab from a webcam, input to ffmpeg and output to player. If not using a swf webcam publisher, what could you use instead?

Right now I have a webcam grab created in flash cs6 which is working but I cannot find necessary instructions on how to add a netstream in actionscript.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do: are you trying to stream webcam input to a browser?

Comment: Yes I am , just like the red5 demo PUBLISHER and view it in my case JWplayer with URL rtmp://foo.com:5080/oflaDemo/livestream

Comment: I am really struggling with the actionscript for Netstream video publishing class and function.

Comment: Using firefox or chrome it should be possible to stream the webcam from one browser to another. You can always try the demo at http://apprtc.appspot.com/

Comment: @brm thanks, looks interesting. Will give it a go.

Comment: @brm I could see this changing the web as we know it except for one thing- looks like only two can take part.

Comment: That's probably just the way that demo application is made. Sending your webcam data to multiple browsers is definitely possible.

Comment: Yes, I did coincidentally read about this technology not long ago.If you listen to the two guys from mozilla and chrome doing demo they do admit there are questions still looming for quality control.